# Method that takes in two predicates and returns a predicate

Tags: java

```
Predicate<T> and(Predicate<T> p1, Predicate<T> p2) {
}
```

I would like to create the above method which creates another Predicate that evaluates to true if the predicates p1 and p2 both evaluate to true.

I would know how to do this if the return type was of boolean but I am unable to think of how to create another Predicate that would resolve this... I have already tried to play around with the andThen method and the test method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already [implemented in the standard library](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#and-java.util.function.Predicate-), but if you wanted to implement it yourself you'd simply pass the parameter to both predicates - `return (operand) -> p1.test(operand) && p2.test(operand);`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Predicate`'s default method `and`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#and-java.util.function.Predicate-) for this purpose.

> Returns a composed predicate that represents a short-circuiting logical AND of this predicate and another.

Use:

```
Predicate<T> and = p1.and(p2);
```

The `Predicate` interface also has `or` and `negate` default methods.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily a [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) already has a method [`Predicate<T> and(Predicate<? super T> other)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#and-java.util.function.Predicate-). built in. You can call

```
Predicate<T> and(Predicate<T> p1, Predicate<T> p2) {
    return p1.and(p2)
}
```